# ntpdate command not found [only when using with cron]

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron, ntpdate

I have a linux machine with ntpdate installed and it is working when i run it from my ssh terminal or from a shell script manually.

However , when i add the shell script to crontab i get the error

ntpdate: command not found

## !/bin/bash

NTPSERVER=192.168.1.192
LOGPATH="/home/test/"
ntpdate -q $NTPSERVER>$LOGPATH/tmp.txt
RETVAL=$?

if [ $RETVAL -ne 0 ] ; then
echo "Failure Unable to query NTP Server :">>$LOGPATH/ntpdebug.txt
date >>$LOGPATH/ntpdebug.txt
exit $RETVAL
fi

echo "Local Time: ">>$LOGPATH/ntpdebug.txt
date >>$LOGPATH/ntpdebug.txt
cat $LOGPATH/tmp.txt>>$LOGPATH/ntpdebug.txt

ntpdate $NTPSERVER
RETVAL1=$?

if [ $RETVAL1 -ne 0 ] ; then
echo "Failure Unable to connect NTP Server :">>$LOGPATH/ntpdebug.txt
date >>$LOGPATH/ntpdebug.txt
exit $RETVAL1
fi

echo "Synchronized" >>$LOGPATH/ntpdebug.txt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use full path!

```
/usr/sbin/ntpdate $NTPSERVER
```

cron doesn't include any `~/.bashrc`, `~/.zshrc`, etc., so the `$PATH` maybe unset.

Comment: There is still folks comming here from google. So ntpdate is deprecated and changed with timedatectl. You can use sudo timedatectl set-ntp on